# need help finding which div element.style is attributed to

Tags: html, css

I'm working in a SaaS program that allows you to enter a custom CSS file with some html as well.  That means I can't remove anything from their code, just override it. I've found an element.style in their code but I can't tell how to override it because I can't find a div or class that it goes with. The line in question is `<div style="margin:5px; width:140px; height:20px; float:right;" align="right">`. I want to change `width: 140px` to `200px`

```
  <div class="boxcontent">
    <div style="width:100%; height:42px;">
      <div style="margin:5px; width:400px; height:30px; float:left;">
        <div class="dashboard_dropdown_btn" id="metric_drop_0">
          <div class="color_image">
            &nbsp;
          </div>

          <div class="text">
            <span id="metric_type_0">Ideas</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dashboard_dropdown_btn" id="metric_drop_1" style=
        "display:none; margin-left:5px;">
          <div class="color_image">
            &nbsp;
          </div>

          <div class="text">
            <span id="metric_type_1">Ideas</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dashboard_dropdown_btn" id="metric_drop_2" style=
        "display:none; margin-left:5px;">
          <div class="color_image">
            &nbsp;
          </div>

          <div class="text">
            <span id="metric_type_2">Ideas</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dashboard_edit_div">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="dashboard_edit_btn">Edit</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div style="margin:5px; width:140px; height:20px; float:right;" align="right">
        <div style="float:left; margin-right:5px; line-height:20px;">
          View by:
        </div>

        <div onclick="selectView('d');" class="select_icon" id="select_day" style=
        "float:left;" rel="on" title="Day"></div>

        <div onclick="selectView('w');" class="select_icon" id="select_week" style=
        "float:left;" title="Week"></div>

        <div onclick="selectView('m');" class="select_icon" id="select_month" style=
        "float:left;" title="Month"></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Where did you find the style? Within the browser's code inspector? Downloading their CSS file?

Comment: Ah - sorry. In Chrome Developer Tools. I can see element.style and then I right clicked for edit html. I'm not sure how to add a screen shot here

Comment: If you would like to add a screenshot to your question, click "edit" underneath it, then click the "image" icon in the WYSIWYG editor options. You can drag-n-drop, upload, or paste a link to an external location (uploading/drag-n-dropping is preferred to prevent link-rot).

Comment: Thanks @TylerH  Man, this is the best damn community.  I've been searching and finding answers here for ages but this is the first question I've ever posted.  Such quick responses and great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.boxcontent>div>div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxcontent">
  <div style="width:100%; height:42px;">
    <div style="margin:5px; width:400px; height:30px; float:left;">
      <div class="dashboard_dropdown_btn" id="metric_drop_0">
        <div class="color_image">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="text">
          <span id="metric_type_0">Ideas</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dashboard_dropdown_btn" id="metric_drop_1" style="display:none; margin-left:5px;">
        <div class="color_image">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="text">
          <span id="metric_type_1">Ideas</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dashboard_dropdown_btn" id="metric_drop_2" style="display:none; margin-left:5px;">
        <div class="color_image">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="text">
          <span id="metric_type_2">Ideas</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dashboard_edit_div">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="dashboard_edit_btn">Edit</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="margin:5px; width:140px; height:20px; float:right;" align="right">
      <div style="float:left; margin-right:5px; line-height:20px;">
        View by:
      </div>

      <div onclick="selectView('d');" class="select_icon" id="select_day" style="float:left;" rel="on" title="Day"></div>

      <div onclick="selectView('w');" class="select_icon" id="select_week" style="float:left;" title="Week"></div>

      <div onclick="selectView('m');" class="select_icon" id="select_month" style="float:left;" title="Month"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```